# How to give an element space from the opposite/same side without using right and left direction in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, padding, margin

Suppose, I have two buttons in HTML-

```
<button class="save">Save</button>
<button class="cancel">Cancel</button>
```

I want to give the `cancel` button a margin of 10px from the left side when it's **LTR** and 10px from the right side when it's **RTL**.

Using Javascript, I can do this very well, like this-

```
let cancel = document.querySelector('.cancel');
// Suppose, the "direction" is an input variable.
cancel.style[direction == 'ltr' ? 'margin-left' : 'margin-right'] = '10px';
```

If I give an example, in the following CSS properties, we only use `start` and `end` values and they adjust the element automatically to the left and right direction according to the page direction.

```
text-align: end;
text-align: start;
justify-content: start;
align-items: end;
```

Something like the above, I want to know if there is any way to set space (either margin or padding) from opposite/same directions without mentioning right and left in CSS.

Many modern frameworks like [Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/spacing/#how-it-works) handle this kind of case (set space according to LTR and RTL) from their inbuilt helper classes (though JS or any CSS property must run behind those concepts) but the question is, is this possible using CSS only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `margin-inline-start: (some value);`, this automatically changes when you switch to **RTL**

Comment: `padding-inline-start` is also a thing!

Comment: Thanks, it really worked. I wonder, how I forgot this CSS property.

Answer (score 1):

***Option 1: Inline margins***

```
.cancel {
  margin-inline-start: 10px;
  writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
  direction: rtl;
}
```

***Option 2: before pseudo-class***

```
.cancel::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
}
```